# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ExportToWkt'

Tags: python, jupyter, wkt

I get this error when I try to run the below code in Jupyter Notebook:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ExportToWkt'

What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
shapefile = osgeo.ogr.Open("C:/Users/chavoshi/Anaconda3/Example Data/Remorquages/pointdata.shp")
layer = shapefile.GetLayer(0)

#First delete the existing contents of this table in case we want to run the code multiple times.
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM B_B")

for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
    lats_o = feature.GetField("latitude_o")
    #print(lats_o)
    lons_o = feature.GetField("longitude_")
    #Get feature geometry
    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    #Convert geometry to WKT format
    wkt = geometry.ExportToWkt()
    #Insert data into database, converting WKT geometry to a PostGIS geography
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO B_B (lats, lons, outline) VALUES ({}, {}, ST_GeogFromText('{}'))".format(lats_o, lons_o, wkt))
 connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call

```
geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
```

is assigning None to geometry.  You need to have a closer look at what's going on there.

Without your full code (or at least a running sample) and a data file, I can't be of much more help.